# Javascript Slider Caption Width By Text

Tags: javascript, css, slider, width, caption

I have Slider Cycle by the clickr landing page by themeforest (i have prchase it).

I add the Slider a caption to the images that work nice, but- there is one thing i need to fix: the caption width!

The caption is the same caption and not change by the width of the text. this is not nice to the eye to see large width with short text.

Here is the JS:

```
// -- Cycle Slider Settings --

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        before: onBeforeCallbackFunction,
        after: onAfterCallbackFunction,
        speed:  1300, 
        timeout: 4000,
        easing:'easeInOutBack',     
        sync:1,
        pause:1,        
        pager:'#pager',     
        // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            return '<li><a href="#"></a></li>'; 
        }
    });
})

function onBeforeCallbackFunction(curr, next, opts) {
    //slide out the caption
    $('.caption').animate({ right: -220}, 300);
    $('.caption one').animate({ right: -120}, 200);
}

function onAfterCallbackFunction(curr, next, opts) {
    var index = opts.currSlide; //zero based index of slides
    // adjust prev/next visibility
    $('#prev')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
    $('#next')[index == opts.slideCount - 1 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
     //  slide in the caption  
    $('.caption').eq(index).animate({ right: 0}, 600);
    console.log(index)
}
```

And here is the CSS:

```
/* -- 4. SLIDER -- */

.caption{ position:absolute; top:75%; background: #333; color:#FFF; font-size:14px; width:200px;height:1em; padding:.5em 5px 10px 5px; right:-220px; z-index:20}

.caption one{ position:absolute; top:75%; background: #333; color:#FFF; font-size:14px; width:100px;height:1em; padding:.5em 5px 10px 5px; right:-120px; z-index:20}

.slider_wrap { position:relative; overflow:hidden; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:392px; height:274px; background:#fbfdff; border:1px solid #e0e4ea; padding:7px; border-radius:6px; -moz-border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px; -khtml-border-radius:6px }
#slider { position:relative; overflow:hidden; margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none }
#slider li { float:left; width:392px; height:274px; overflow:hidden }
#pager { position:relative; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; margin:0px; padding:12px 0px 0px; list-style:none; z-index:999; line-height:0px; background:url(images/slider_shadow.png) 50% 0px no-repeat }
#pager li { display:inline-block; width:10px; margin:0px 2px }
#pager li a { display:block; width:10px; height:11px; background:url(images/pager.png) -14px 0px no-repeat }
#pager li.activeSlide a { background-position:0px 0px }
```

See here the page: [Clickr Slider Cycle](http://cor.co.il/landing/click/index.html)

Or if you prefer: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/yWdSe/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem comes from the set `width=200px;`. In order to make it adjustable, locate the following code in `style.css`:

```
.caption{ ..... width:200px; }
```

and change it to `width: auto;`. This should make the caption width as wide as the text.

Comment: No. This change should be applied to `style.css` file and it will not affect the `js` code.